# Cannot implement interface member because it does not have the matching return type of List<IInterface>

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

I have interfaces `IChild` and `IParent`. `IParent` has a member that is a `List<IChild>`.

I wish to have classes that implement `IParent` where each class has a member that implements `IChild`:

```
public interface IChild
{ 
}  

public interface IParent
{  
    List<IChild> a { get; set; }
} 

public class ChildA : IChild
{ 
} 

public class ChildB : IChild
{ 
} 

public class ParentA : IParent
{ 
    public List<ChildA> a { get; set; }
}

public class ParentB : IParent
{ 
    public List<ChildB> a { get; set; }
}
```

But, this code will not compile. The error is:

```
`MyApp.Data.ParentA` does not implement interface member `MyApp.Data.IParent.a`.
`MyApp.Data.ParentA.a` cannot implement `MyApp.Data.IParent.a` because it does not have
the matching return type of `System.Collections.Generic.List<MyApp.Data.IChild>`.
```

Comment: It would be wiser to declare your `List` properties as `IList`s, they would be less retrictive but offer the same functionality. Doesn't help with the question though.

Comment: then he can make it just `IEnumerable`. That may not be the requirement

Comment: @Jodrell `IList` does not offer the same functionality as `List`.

Comment: @Suncat2000, you are correct but, `IList`, `ICollection` (thier readonly counterparts) or `IEnumerable` might be a smaller promise to make that does meet the required level of functionality.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Make IParent generic:

```
public interface IChild
{
}

public interface IParent<TChild> where TChild : IChild
{
    List<TChild> a { get; set; } 
}

public class ChildA : IChild {  }   

public class ChildB : IChild {  }   

public class ParentA : IParent<ChildA>
{
    public List<ChildA> a { get; set; }
}

public class ParentB : IParent<ChildB>
{
    public List<ChildB> a { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I really wish I could upvote this 100 times...this is a case study on why generics are so useful.

Comment: Can you elaborate about the rationale behind the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the classes return a `List<IChild>`:

```
public class ParentA : IParent
{ 
    public List<IChild> a { get; set; }
}

public class ParentB : IParent
{ 
    public List<IChild> a { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this was up-voted. This won't compile. You can't convert a `List<ChildX>` to or from a `List<IChild>`.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation can only return List of IChild as follows:

```
public interface IChild
{
}

public interface IParent
{
    List<IChild> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ChildA : IChild
{
}

public class ChildB : IChild
{
}

public class ParentA : IParent
{

    public List<IChild> Children
    {
        get;
        set;

    }
}

public class ParentB : IParent
{
    public List<IChild> Children
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A collection of `IChild` cannot be implicitly converted to a collection of its child type

Change the return type of `IParent.a` to `List<ChildA>` **OR** change the property declaration on `ParentA` and `ParentB` to `public List<IChild> a { get; set; }`.  I recommend the latter, as I think that is what you're most likely going for.

Comment: Do you mean, change the property declarations on `ParentA` and `ParentB`? The one on `IParent` is already a `List<IChild>`.

Comment: Yes, you will have to change the declarations on your implementing classes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement where I had two different methods that operated on two different classes but had the same logic in it for the properties that are common to both the classes.

so I thought to use inheritance and generics for this to write a common method, I was able to achieve in the following way.

```
namespace OOPS.Interfaces
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public interface IBanner
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IBannerContent<T> where T : IBanner
    {
        List<T> Banners { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Simple Model.

```
namespace OOPS.Simple
{
    using Interfaces;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class Banner : IBanner
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class BannerContent : IBannerContent<Banner>
    {
        public List<Banner> Banners { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Complex Model.

```
namespace OOPS.Complex
{
    using Interfaces;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class Banner : IBanner
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class BannerContent : IBannerContent<Banner>
    {
        public List<Banner> Banners { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The common business logic and sample invocation. The key part here is using the `where` clause to constrain the type such as `where T : IBanner` all the way down till the method we want it to be common.

```
namespace OOPS
{
    using Interfaces;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class BusinessLogic
    {
        public void Print<T>(IBannerContent<T> bannerContent) where T : IBanner
        {
            foreach (var item in bannerContent.Banners)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var banner1 = new Simple.BannerContent
            {
                Banners = new List<Simple.Banner>
                {
                    new Simple.Banner { Name = "Banner 1" },
                    new Simple.Banner { Name = "Banner 2" }
                }
            };

            var banner2 = new Complex.BannerContent
            {
                Banners = new List<Complex.Banner>
                {
                    new Complex.Banner { Name = "Banner 3", Description = "Test Banner" },
                    new Complex.Banner { Name = "Banner 4", Description = "Design Banner" }
                }
            };

            var business = new BusinessLogic();
            business.Print(banner1);
            business.Print(banner2);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```